# How to disable downloadButton when there is no reactive data?

Tags: r, shiny

I've searched the internet fruitlessly for help with this, but not finding what I need for my specific needs.

I'm designing an app where the user uploads multiple files, those files are stored in a list and manipulated, and then the user downloads the resulting .xlsx file.

I want to disable `downloadButton()` if the list where I store the files is empty. The problem is, the `observe()` function does not seem to recognize it because it is reactive. Here is an example:

```
library(shiny)
library(purrr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("site",
            accept = "csv",
            multiple = TRUE),
  actionButton("submit", "Submit"),
  downloadButton("download", "Download")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  
  files_list <- eventReactive(input$submit, {
    files <- req(input$submit)
    data <- map(files$datapath, read.csv)
    dataSplit <- split(data, ceiling(seq_along(data)/23))
    dataSplit
  })
  
  observe({
    shinyjs::toggleState("download", condition = length(files_list() != 0)) # this doesn't work
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Is there a way to disable the `downloadButton()` if that reactive list is empty?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Try with `length( list() ) != 0`. Besides, using `list` as a variable name or name of function or name of a reactive is a bad choice as it conflicts with the R `list()` function. Perhaps `files_list` would be a better choice.

Comment: Ah sorry, in my app it is named something different, I used `list` here just to make it easy - just edited the OP. I tried what you suggested though and sadly that wasn't the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code. Besides the minor issue with the wrongly placed parenthesis in your condition which I already mentioned in my comment you have to add `shinyjs::useShinyjs()` to the UI to use `shinyjs`. Second, a `fileInput` requires a `label`. As is your code results in an error. Third, you have to use `files <- req(input$site)`. Your file path is not stored in the action button. Finally, the issue is not that `files_list` is a `reactive` but that your condition results in an error as `files_list()` gets only initialized after the `submit` button is pressed. Perhaps there is a better option, but the only option I figured out is to use an auxillary `reactiveVal()` to store the state of your condition.

```r
library(shiny)
library(purrr)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  fileInput(
    "site",
    NULL,
    accept = "csv",
    multiple = TRUE
  ),
  actionButton("submit", "Submit"),
  downloadButton("download", "Download")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  enable_download <- reactiveVal(value = FALSE)
  
  files_list <- eventReactive(input$submit, {
    files <- req(input$site)
    data <- map(files$datapath, read.csv)
    dataSplit <- split(data, ceiling(seq_along(data) / 23))
    dataSplit
  })

  observe({
    req(files_list())
    enable_download(length(files_list()) != 0)
  })
  
  observe({
    toggleState(
      id = "download",
      condition = enable_download()
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8717
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like it will work! Apologies for my code - I tried to make an easier to digest reprex and clearly missed some important steps. I will let you know how it goes when I return to work!